# Text to SQL query framework

Tags: sql, nlp

I am looking for a framework to translate text/questions/sentences to SQL queries given a relational database schema.

For instance, assuming to refer to the Northwind database, the system should translate "show me orders in 2017" to `select * from orders where year(orderdate) = 2017`.

As to the literature, there are plenty of papers in this research direction. Still, none of them seems to provide open and usable frameworks. As to the open source projects, the implemented approaches are often broken or too naive.

Do you have references for existing and working frameworks?

Comment: Note that [this](https://github.com/lerocha/chinook-database) is a FOSS alternative to Northwinds. Great question; I really hope that you get an answer